# Javascript : for loop doesn't work with array.length

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, for-loop, local-storage

I want to do a for loop, in which `var i`, will increase by 1 for each element in my array. But, `i` doesn't increase, it log me "0" even if my array have something in it. I've logged array.length just to check if it works in the for loop, and it does.

So, I don't know what the problem is. I've tried many things, many ways to define my array just to make "for" loop works.

This is the code :

```
let button = document.getElementById("addToCartButton");
console.log(button);
button.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("kuku le bouton");
    let amountInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
    let select = document.getElementById("colors");
    let productFinalDetails = Object.assign({}, productDetails, {
        color: `${select.value}`,
        quantity: amountInput.value,
    });
    let productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));
    console.log(productArray);
    if (productArray == null ) {
        productArray = [];
        productArray.push(productFinalDetails);
        localStorage.setItem("product", JSON.stringify(productArray));
        productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product"));
        console.log(productArray.length);
    } else if (productArray != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(productArray.length);
        }
    }
};
```

And here are google console screens !

[image: google console]

[image: localStorage]

Comment: Your array has one item in it, so it logs that one item. That item has an index of 0 since it is the first item in the array. After that item the index becomes 1 which is not less than the length of the array (also 1) so it stops

Comment: You have one item in the array, so the loop run once with the index of 0. I don't see the problem here

Comment: This item have an index of 0, i understand, but i just want my i to get equal to the lengh of productArray, so, even if the first element have an index of 0, this is an element in productArray, so "i" must increase by 1, no ? I don't know, I just think.

Comment: @remsB - It does, which is why your loop ends. It's just that you don't log that new value, because the loop ended.

Comment: @remsB The `i` will be `1` if you log it out after the loop. Because the loop ends after `i` increases by `1` and no longer meets the condition `i < productArray.length`.

Comment: Oh wow, guys, okay, sorry, i'm a very beginner at javascript and i just didn't understood that I was out of the "for" loop when i was asking the console to log me "i". Thx you very much for giving me the clue, I've resolved my problem. Have a nice day everyone !

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `i` in your code

You do too many things on click

You likely meant to do this

```js
let productData = localStorage.getItem("product");
let productArray = productData ? JSON.parse(productData) : [];
let button = document.getElementById("addToCartButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("kuku le bouton");
  let amountInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
  let select = document.getElementById("colors");
  let productFinalDetails = {
    color: select.value,
    quantity: amountInput.value
  };
  productArray.push(productFinalDetails);

  localStorage.setItem("product", JSON.stringify(productArray));
});
```

If you have more than one button, you need to change ID to class and delegate from the container

```js
let productData = localStorage.getItem("product");
let productArray = productData ? JSON.parse(productData) : [];
document.getElementById("cartContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("button")) return; 
  console.log("kuku le bouton");
  const itemDiv = tgt.closest("div");
  let amount = itemDiv.querySelector(".quantity").value;
  let color = itemDiv.querySelector(".colors").value
  let productFinalDetails = {
    color: color,
    quantity: amount
  };
  productArray.push(productFinalDetails);

  localStorage.setItem("product", JSON.stringify(productArray));
});
```

Comment: Oh wow, guys, okay, sorry, i'm a very beginner at javascript and i just didn't understood that I was out of the "for" loop when i was asking the console to log me "i".

Thx you very much for giving me the clue, I've resolved my problem. Have a nice day everyone !